# getchar returns unexpected character

Tags: c, gcc

I try to compile this code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void print(FILE *a)
{
int main();
int count=20;
int c;
int stop=0;
char answer;

while(!stop){
    while((c=getc(a))!=EOF){
            fprintf(stdout,"%c",c);
            if(c=='\n'){
                    count--;
                    if(!count){
                        printf("do you want continue:y=for continue/q=for quit");
                        fflush(stdin);
                            answer=getchar();
                        if(answer=='y' || answer=='Y')
                            count=20;
                        else if(answer=='Q' || answer=='q'){
                            printf("you quit this program,press any key and hit the enter to close");
                            stop=1;
                            break;
                            }
                        else{
                            printf("argument is unacceptable,rolling back action");
                            main();
                            }
                        }
                }
        }
    if(c==EOF)
        stop=1;
    }
}
void halt()/*do nothing just for halt and waiting for input*/
{
int a;

scanf("%d",&a);
}
int main()
{
FILE *in,*fopen();
char name1[25];
int a;

printf("enter the name of the file you want to show:");
scanf("%24s",name1);
in=fopen(name1,"r");
if(in==NULL){
    printf("the files doesnt exist or it is in another directory, try to enter again\n");
    main();
        }
else
    print(in);

fclose(in);
halt();

return 0;
}
```

what is really matter is this part:

```
if(!count){
    printf("do you want continue:y=for continue/q=for quit");
    fflush(stdin);
    answer=getchar();
    if(answer=='y' || answer=='Y')
         count=20;
    else if(answer=='Q' || answer=='q'){
         printf("you quit this program,press any key and hit the enter to close");
         stop=1;
         break;
    }
    else{
         printf("argument is unacceptable,rolling back action");
         main();
    }
}
```

The program is expected to show 20 line content of a file, but when i run it in terminal, something goes off when it come to `if-else`part it tend to execute the else whichever i put in the in the `answer`variable.did i do something wrong

NB:i have tried this code with different compiler such as lcc-win32 and it works fine.

Comment: i just emphasize it. the problem is in logical expression but it seem the `getchar()` is skipped so the `answer variable ` doesnt get any value, so it tend to execute the else part. but if it like that, then why?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what the problem is, this is based on a pairded down q&d example of your code and works as expected.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  char  answer;

  while(1) {
    printf("\ndo you want continue:y=for continue/q=for quit: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    answer=getchar();

    if(answer=='y' || answer=='Y')
      puts("y/Y entered");
    else if(answer=='Q' || answer=='q'){
      puts("q/Q entered");
      break;
    }
    else
      puts("Something other than q/y entered.");
  }
}
```

Unfortunatley, I'm pressed for time right now, so I can't check if there are any substantial differences between your version and mine .. I don't recall anything.

This was tested with gcc 4.4.3 under Ubuntu.

See if this works for you.

Comment: The problem is OP has a `scanf` call before which means there is a newline in stdin

Comment: @UlrichDangel Ah .. I see now. Yes. I just took the shorter code presented at the bottom of OP's post to work with.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `fflush(stdin)` is not standardized and behaves different on different system. For more information have a look at at http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html and http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html

So what is happening here: You are using `scanf("%24s",name1);` to read data from stdin, e.g a user enters a filename (e.g. `test.c` and presses <kbd>Return</kbd>. `stdin` now contains `test.c\n`. `scanf` reads now up to 24 characters from stdin, in our case `test.c`and leaves `\n` in `stdin`, this means `stdin` contains now `\n`. The `fflush(stdin)` call does not remove `\n` from `stdin` which means your `getchar()` call will read `\n` from stdin which explains the described behavior.

#### Content of stdin over time

1. Before `scanf`: <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>\n</kbd>
2. After `scanf`: <kbd>\n</kbd> - scanf used `test.c` and assigned it to `name1`
3. After `fflush(stdin)`: <kbd>\n</kbd>
4. After `getchar()`: empty as `getchar` read and returned `\n`

For more information about this exact problem and maybe a better description have a look at the [c-faq entry about fflush vs. gets](http://c-faq.com/stdio/gets_flush2.html)